# Geometric Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find geometric progression if $a_1 = 3$, $S_n = 2343$, $a_n = 1875$.

I'm trying to use sum formula $S_n = a_1\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}$, but can't do much. I'm a bit lost so if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equations
$$a_n=a_1r^{n-1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad r^{n-1}=625$$
and
$$S_n=a_1\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1-r^n=781(1-r)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Since, $a_n =1875$

$\implies ar^{n-1}=1875$ where a is the first term of the G.P.

$\implies r^{n-1}=625$

$\implies r^{n-1}=5^4$

So, r=5 and n=5.

So the series is $3,15,75,375,1875...$

$Check:$
Adding the terms becomes $3+15+75+375+1875=2343$

Answer (score 0):

You just need formula for the nth term of G.P., which is $a.r^{n-1}$

$ar^{n-1}=3.r^{n-1}=1875$

$\therefore r^{n-1}=625=5^4$

$\therefore r=5, n=5$

with this we can construct G.P.